# symfony 5 Configuration path "security.access_control" cannot be overwritten. error?

Tags: symfony, facebook-login, symfony5

I was trying to integrate social login using in symfony 5 using [this link](https://hugo-soltys.com/blog/easily-implement-facebook-login-with-symfony-4) I have followed the steps provided in the link but I think something wrong has happened from my end and it continuously giving me this error.

> Configuration path "security.access_control" cannot be overwritten. You have to define all options for this path, and any of its sub-paths in one configuration section.

I am working on the dev mode and it says the above error.

even when I try to `php bin/console cache:clear` it gives me this one.

```
 // Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false


In BaseNode.php line 294:

  Configuration path "security.access_control" cannot be overwritten. You have to define all options for this path, and any of its sub-paths in one configuration section.
```

Here is the my security.yaml file

```yaml
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Members:
            algorithm: bcrypt
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt


    providers:
        members:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Members
                property: username_email
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
            
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        admin:
            pattern:            /management
            context:            user
            form_login:
                provider:       app_user_provider
                login_path:     /management/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /management/login_check
                failure_path:   null
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormBackAuthenticator
                provider: app_user_provider
            logout:
                path:           /management/logout
                target:         /management/login
            anonymous:          true

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            context: members
            form_login:
                provider:       members
                login_path:     front_security_login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
                provider: members
            
            logout:
                path:           front_security_logout
                target:         front_index
            anonymous:          true

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN]
        ROLE_USER: [ROLE_USER]

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/(%locales%)/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        #- { path: ^/(%locales%)/my-profile/*, allow_if: "is_fully_authenticated()" }
        - { path: ^/(%locales%)/mon_profil/*, allow_if: "is_fully_authenticated()" }
        #- { path: ^/(%locales%)/صفحتي/*, allow_if: "is_fully_authenticated()" }
        #- { path: ^/(%locales%)/add-new-advert/*, allow_if: "is_fully_authenticated()" }
        - { path: ^/(%locales%)/ajouter-nouvelle-annonce, allow_if: "is_fully_authenticated()" }
        #- { path: ^/(%locales%)/أضف-إعلان-جديد/*, allow_if: "is_fully_authenticated()" }
        - { path: ^/management/password-recover, allow_if: "!is_fully_authenticated()" }
        - { path: ^/management/reset-password/*, allow_if: "!is_fully_authenticated()" }
        - { path: ^/management/login, allow_if: "!is_fully_authenticated()" }
        - { path: ^/management/register, allow_if: "!is_fully_authenticated()" }
        - { path: ^/management/account-confirm/*, allow_if: "!is_fully_authenticated()" }
        - { path: ^/management/ajax/generate-password, allow_if: "!is_fully_authenticated()" }
        - { path: ^/management/ajax/reset-password, allow_if: "!is_fully_authenticated()" }
        - { path: ^/management, allow_if: "is_fully_authenticated()" }
        - { path: ^/management/ajax, allow_if: "is_fully_authenticated()" }
```

Comment: You have this error because the `access_control:`is defined in another YAML file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same problem (Symfony 5.2).

So I completely removed my `security.access_control`
from my `config/packages/security.yaml`

The next error message was:

```
Because you have multiple guard authenticators, you need to set the "guard.entry_point" key to one of your authenticators (App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator, App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator).
```

Although I have only one authenticator `App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator`.

I read the docs on guard authentication [Guard Authentication](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_guard_authenticators.html#multiple-authenticators-with-shared-entry-point) and discovered that this problem appears to result from multiple authentication systems.

And finally found the solution (at least for my case):
I added the `entry_point` config in my guard authenticator:

```
guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator
            entry_point: App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator <-- new config that saved me.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `public/index.php` and `bin/console.php`, I Solved this problem when i replaced the following line.

```
(new Dotenv())->bootEnv(dirname(__DIR__).'/.env');
```

with

```
(new Dotenv())->overload(dirname(__DIR__).'/.env');
```

with xdebug i can see that `$_SERVER['APP_ENV']` is empty.

[image]

this is the .env

[image: .env file]

Answer (score 0):

Ever since the default Symfony went to 5.1.x I've had this on any type of symfony created project (minimal or full).
While I have not found a way to get 5.1.x to work, rolling back to 5.0.x seems to work.

If I find out out an fix or 5.1.x gets fixed I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in Symfony 4.4

After 2 hours struggling, I fixed this error by DELETING this import in framework.yaml

> imports:
> - { resource: security.yaml }

As the error message indicates, this error happens because "You have to define all options for this path, and any of its sub-paths in ***ONE*** configuration section."

Which means you need to to find if your securities options/configs are used/defined in more than one places, then put it into just one place.

In my case, it happens because i imported security.yaml inside framework.yaml
(legacy code from symfony 2.6, this is unnecessary after I upgraded to symfony 4.4)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a really simple reason: i had this error (Sf4) because i backuped the config file security.yaml to _security.yaml. Symfony reads both...